# SaveAs in Excel Throws an Error on VB.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to make a program that trims the excel file. I want to keep the original file and just save as the new copy to a new destination with a modified name. My code gives me an error and I'm not sure what I'm missing. Also, is there any way to actually just add a range to delete columns/rows instead of doing it one by one?

Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in PO Trimmer.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in PO Trimmer.exe
The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:

- Make sure the specified folder exists.
- Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
- Make sure the filename and folder path do not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *
- Make sure the filename and folder path do not contain more than 218 characters.

  ```
    Dim xlApp As Application
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet

    If txtTarget.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select the file you wish to convert!", vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, "Missing Target File")
        btnBrowseTarget.PerformClick()
    ElseIf txtDestination.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select the folder to save your file!", vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, "Missing Destination Folder")
        btnBrowseDestination.PerformClick()
    Else
        xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtTarget.Text)
        xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

        If rbtnSeca.Checked = True Then
            Dim rg As Excel.Range

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("N")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("M")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("L")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("K")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("J")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("I")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("H")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("F")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("E")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("D")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("B")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Columns("A")
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            rg = xlSheet.Rows(1)
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()

            Dim convertSuccess As Integer = MsgBox("Trimming success.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Excel Trim")

            xlBook.SaveAs(txtDestination.Text & "PO_" & Today & "_" & TimeOfDay, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
            xlApp.Quit()


        ElseIf rbtnMS.Checked = True Then

        End If
    End If
  ```

Comment: Does this need a path.combine? "txtDestination.Text & "PO_" & Today & "_" & TimeOfDay". Another option is to record a macro in excel and see how the VBA looks and then replicate that for range selection and deletion.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer I just wanted the Saved As file to be named as that plus the date and time but apparently, it's giving me an error on that specific line and I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Put your filename into a variable and inspect it. I think you might see what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know what `Workbook` is with Option Strict on (it should always be on). I was able to qualify with `Excel` because of my Imports statement.

I changed the message box format. The values need the bitwise `Or` to combine the correct flags.

It is not a good idea to call events. This can have other implications. Move the code to a separate method and call that from this code and button click code.

Don't create you `Excel` objects until your conditions are met. I was able to shorten the code a bit by combining contiguous ranges.

Quit is not going to completely clean up the interop objects. There are loads of pages on the internet dealing with this problem.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Private Sub btnBrowseDestination_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBrowseDestination.Click
    BrowseDestination()
End Sub

Private Sub btnBrowseTarget_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgas) Handles btnBrowseTarget.Click
    BrowseTarget()
End Sub

Private Sub BrowseTarget()
    'Code moved from btnBrowseTarget.Click
End Sub

Private Sub BrowseDestination()
    'Code moved from btnBrowseDestination.Click
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If txtTarget.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select the file you wish to convert!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation Or MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Missing Target File")
        BrowseTarget()
    ElseIf txtDestination.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select the folder to save your file!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation Or MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Missing Destination Folder")
        BrowseDestination()
    Else
        If rbtnSeca.Checked = True Then
            Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application()
            Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtTarget.Text)
            xlSheet = DirectCast(xlBook.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
            Dim rg = DirectCast(xlSheet.Columns("H:N"), Excel.Range)
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()
            rg = DirectCast(xlSheet.Columns("D:F"), Excel.Range)
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()
            rg = DirectCast(xlSheet.Columns("A:B"), Excel.Range)
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()
            rg = DirectCast(xlSheet.Rows(1), Excel.Range)
            rg.Select()
            rg.Delete()
            Dim convertSuccess As Integer = MsgBox("Trimming success.", MsgBoxStyle.Information Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Excel Trim")
            xlBook.SaveAs(txtDestination.Text & "PO_" & Today & "_" & TimeOfDay, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
            xlApp.Quit()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice that you gave and I will keep them in mind. But apparently, it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Check your windows Task Manager. Go all the way down the list looking for Excel and End Task. A previous try could still be holding the file. Google on how to get rid of Excel interop.

Comment: The TimeOfDay was actually messing it up. Removing it fixed the issue, but would be nice if I could add the time in the file name too.

Comment: @Foxseiz I don't see why that would cause a problem. The only thing I can think of is that together with the path it is too long.

Comment: Because the time has colons, I did change the format of the time and it worked. I used - instead of : and that did the trick.